# Rails 6 Ajax request not working, SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' cars:1 is AJAX broken in Rails 6?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

I am having this issue in an app I am developing and couldn't figure out why I am getting the error so I created a vanilla test app and generated a simple scaffold cars using

```
rails g scaffold cars name
```

Then I added a simple div to the cars index.html.erb file

```
<div id="cars">
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>
```

So that now the index.heml.erb looks like this

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Cars</h1>
<div id="cars">
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @cars.each do |car| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= car.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', car %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(car) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', car, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Car', new_car_path %>
```

So far a totally vanilla Rails 6 app with a vanilla scaffold plus an added HTML div

With the addition of a link_to remote: true in the layout my application layout now looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ajaxtest</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= link_to "Cars", cars_path, remote: true %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Again a totally vanilla Rails 6 application.html.erb with the exception of the new ajax link to the cars index action
The idea here is to simply replace "hello" with "Boo" on the cars index page.

So now to deal with the controller, I added a check for javascript format in the index action of the cars controller so I now have this

```
  def index
    @cars = Car.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

  end
```

So far so good. Running the app and using the cars link produces, as expected an error in the Rails log telling me it can't find the view it needs to render. No console errors in the browser so all is hooked up and working.

So I create a cars.js.erb template with the following code that should replace the word "Hello" with the word "Boo" like so.

```
car = document.getElementById("cars")
car.innerHTML = "<%= j render("Boo") %>"
```

This gives me a console error in my browser (Firefox) of `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' cars:1`

Quite clearly there is no "<" on line 1 of the cars template.

with an empty cars.js.erb I try again and the same `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' cars:1`

This is the same error I get in my original app which caused me to setup this test app.

I can place erb code, I can try even a simple console.log in the js.erb template but the error persists and nothing works.
Just as a precaution I wash, rinse, repeat the above but restarting the server with every change of the cars.js.erb template.

Conclusion: Ajax is busted in Rails 6 out of the box, so what do I have to do to make it work? Something in webpacker is injecting something maybe? I haven't a clue as to where to start looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is due to naming your SJR template `cars.js.erb` instead of `index.js.erb`.  The `index` action renders templates named `index` by default.  When Rails doesn't find `index.js.erb`, it renders `index.html.erb` instead, which causes the SyntaxError when its evaluated as JavaScript.

To fix this, you can rename `cars.js.erb` to `index.js.erb`, or you can change your `format.js` call to `format.js { render "cars" }`.

Also, to save you future trouble, I should point out that `render("Boo")` does not render the word "Boo", but, rather, attempts to render the partial template named "_Boo".